# TS use return type of function as param in the other function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a `define` function which needs the `options` param. There are two functions in the `options`, `setup` and `action`, I wanna the return type of `setup` can be used as the param type of `action`.

```js
define( {
    setup() {
        return { field: "empty" };
    },
    action( param /* { field: string } */ ) {
    }
} )
```

**edit:** [example ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdhACgGwK4HMUHkxhEB7ZAHhgD4oBeKAbwCgpWoBDLYACxICcAXFADOwPihwBuFmwAm7YOwD8QmNIC+0pgGMM7YcKgBhEgFtT7ZLMaam8LMm3EyUbXwgKI5ACpQIAD2AIK0NRcWQcKgAKV1NZIV8ASiETc0trZgBId2AsPmQoVAB3YzMLKyjEjSYmUEhYBBQIVPLZAFkIHhJZYR8aemY2KAB6Ydd3TyhEQ3YoeHYnfhA5hydSZBlWYU6sMBjtMvShOogSeHGPIKhkqG9pTIXnZBj5RQTroQA3EkRZatrwNAAJLIVB8NDsPjsUy9ah0RibKAAEle7FUGi0ATA-GAK0cTygskaqEwuBQ5CYmRgfkCwR6UAAShADnxZOQwhIADQcZAgKicxEgsHwoUQcGQ6G9AByZClWAwegARhgvNQqExopSSER1sIBJSqcT0Ng8MhCE9KDQAGQG7zcabeQGWpg3QZsUZQAAGaD42s9NMgTigPGgOTyBROUDOXu2uTAnspRKQqBa6XIPu1msymW1Tz1BsNyeahysHS6PXTvrA1oLdodTtFfHVmRujY0COyO3yHcySaaqasQhiud11zoNBiDHU10ptnUNQ9AFF-NCwCruUCOKZg3xlsASISIJ8IBhtRwoJ8sNBRCAVRwwIgdGRRFA12SCvQ+ySTShJ5TOF0ghQAARPAJAkMBAq9goaI9oqkJCAAjLOTDTlUC5jHWhjTMG3DQJ6X4QP69j4usT7IC+BxpFY8JvqaAB0hEDrIf6ZLGuz7CW1iJD2Hqesx-o4bM2jcOwKDsMq0AoKIljaBA3LJuwCrLEUiAKlAYb5AaHqzBYYCQNYJzchgiAANbQAwUCmBABjsDgEBCByETcsQ1nCCohRYKYipilA87ZppBRUa0MTARAphECAwHXPc6hQY86wvDBIwAFQBsyuIhhpXYRoCUbnOxYDcoqXBQA4pnICQRQFJVJQpWMPFTqhMVAA)

I've reduced the code as much as possible, but since I'm not sure if the part other than define can be improved, I've released the rest.

```js
type DefinePluginOption<D> = {
    author: string;
    data?: D;
};

class Command {};
function create<T extends string>( cmd: T ): Command {
    return new Command();
}

type DefineCommandMethods<T> = {
    // create is a factory function
    setup( command: typeof create ): T;
    action( data: T ): void;
}

type InnerParams<D> = {
    $data: D;
};

export function definePlugin<
    D extends Record<string, any>,
    Inner = InnerParams<NonNullable<D>>
>(
    options:
        DefinePluginOption<D> &
        ThisType<D>
): {
    // `Prop` expect the return type of `setup`
    defineCommand<Prop>(
        options:
            DefineCommandMethods<Prop> &
            ThisType<Inner>
    ): Inner;
} {
    return {
        defineCommand: ( options ) => ( {} )
    };
}

// Example, I am try to develop a vue style api
const plugin = definePlugin( {
    author: "foo",
    data: {
        bar: 1
    }
} );

// This is the `define` function
const command = plugin.defineCommand( {
    setup( command ) {
        // `Command` is a chainable instance, finally will return
        // a mapped type, like { message: string, times?: number }
        return command( "empty" );
    },
    action( data /* expect the return type of setup, but unknown now */ ) {}
} );
```

Comment: Is `function define<T>(arg: {setup(): T; action(param: T): void}) { ... }` what you're looking for?

Comment: @kaya3 that would make sense but TS can't really do that kind of simultaneous generic-and-contextual inference from a single argument, see [ms/TS#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872).  The best you can do here if you want inference is to split up that object into multiple arguments like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYvJEw).  SilveryStar does that address your question, and should I write up an answer? Or am I missing something about what you're looking for?

Comment: @jcalz I'm so sorry for taking so long to reply to you. It looks like the `{ field: "empty" }` must appear in the function? I'm not sure, but in my code, the `define` must comes from the other generics function, like `const define = otherFn( {} )`. so I dont know can this way solve it? Could you help me? I can provide more codes.

Comment: Yes, you should provide a [mre] of the issue you're facing.

Comment: @jcalz I have edited the question and added the example in it, could you give the solution or the other way to achieve it?

Comment: Please include the example as plain text also (an external link is a good supplement to, but it is not a replacement for, plain text.)  I don't see a function named `define()` in that code, and there's a lot of stuff going on that I'm not sure is directly relevant.  Note that a [mre] should be *minimal*, meaning the least amount of code necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: For example: in `D extends Record<string, any>, Data = NonNullable<D>, Inner = InnerParams<Data>`, you seem to be using generic parameter defaults as a way to give names to other types, but this can mess with type inference.  If you want to talk about `InnerParams<NonNullable<D>>` then just use that directly with a single `D` type parameter.  Is `NonNullable` important for the question?  If not, then try to remove it.  Make the example smaller, so there's less potentially distracting content for others who want to help to deal with.

Comment: you are right, I try my best to do it, could you have a look now